# Coarsened Exact Matching

Tags: r, matching, na

I am trying to run Coarsened Exact Matching on a dataset of 6549 observations and 94 variables. I have eliminated NAs and am running matching on "Polity2>/ 7" (treatment). However when I come to running the command I am faced with the following error message:

```r
mat<-cem(treatment="Polity2>=7",data = Matched2a, drop = "todrop")
```

```r
Error in names(obj$group.idx) <- paste("G", obj$g.names, sep = "") : 

'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In reduce.var(data[[i]], cutpoints[[vnames[i]]]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In reduce.var(data[[i]], cutpoints[[vnames[i]]]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Could someone please explain to me what these error messages mean?

Comment: How to reproduce the issue? [mcve]

Comment: To help solve the issue - I keep getting this error message and am not understanding how to progress

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the treatment variable column to the data.